# Zakat on plots bought with intention to resale

Tags: fiqh, zakat

I am a working woman.My husband got a plot from his parents and we plan to build a house for us but we don't have enough money for that so I bought two more plots intending to sale on profit to raise fund for building house.We are living in rented house n Allhamdulillah earning well.Please answer with reference and as early as possible because its been over a year that I bought the plots but did not sell as waiting for some profitable sale.